# What is the difference between mineral groups and series?

Tags: geology, geochemistry, mineralogy

It seems to me when reading about minerals, groups and series are spoken about interchangably in similar types of contexts. Is there a difference? If so, what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference.

A mineral **series** represents mineral which have a well defined solid solution. One of the most known examples is olivine: olivine is not a strictly defined chemical composition for a mineral, but rather a series between the forsterite end-member (Mg<sub>2</sub>SiO<sub>4</sub>) and fayalite end-member (Fe<sub>2</sub>SiO<sub>4</sub>). Note that if you find a pure end-member in nature, then you have a mineral **species**. Quite rare for olivine though. There's also the olivine **group**, which consists of other minerals that do not form a solid solution with the forsterite-fayalite series (for example monticellite CaMgSiO<sub>4</sub>) or minerals that do form a solid solution, except that it's extremely rare in nature (for example tephroite Mn<sub>2</sub>SiO<sub>4</sub>). Here's a comprehensive list of the minerals in the olivine group: http://www.mindat.org/min-29264.html

Another example is the pyroxene **group**. So for simple Ca-Mg-Fe pyroxenes, you have the clinopyroxene and orthopyroxene **series**, which consist of the end-members (**species**, if you find them pure) diopside (CaMgSiO<sub>6</sub>) - hedenbergite (CaFeSiO<sub>6</sub>) and enstatite (MgSiO<sub>3</sub>) - ferrosilite (FeSiO<sub>3</sub>), respectively. Intermediate clinopyroxenes are also called augite.

The distinction is not always clear. For example, the feldspar **group** traditionally has the plagioclase **series** (albite-anorthite, NaAlSi<sub>3</sub>O<sub>8</sub>-CaAl<sub>2</sub>Si<sub>2</sub>O<sub>8</sub>) and the K-feldspar **species** (KAlSi<sub>3</sub>O<sub>8</sub>, either microcline, orthoclase or sanidine, depending on structure). But in some cases there is a solid solution between albite and K-feldspar, forming the alkali-feldspar **series**. Nature doesn't always behave according to our rules, and it's important to remember that our classification systems work well with ideal systems but break down often.

[Further reading](http://courses.missouristate.edu/emantei/mineralogy/mineral%20classif.html)